# What are some cool things I can do with Backtrack?

Tags: security, wifi, linux

I've been interested in trying out [BackTrack](http://www.remote-exploit.org/backtrack.html) for a while, but I'm not sure how to use most of the tools. I know there's a lot there, but is there a simple, graphical way to monitor activity on my wireless network? Instructions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Backtrack is a funny one. It certainly has a lot of tools in one place but you still need to be running compatible hardware to use them (particularly wireless tools).

I would strongly recommend doing some of the tutorials and installing the programmes you need on a dedicated linux computer as you need them.

Understanding how to install & use the tools is the important thing.

Most of the techniques rely on having multiple terminals open and either scanning/spoofing/injecting or recording packets of information.

There is very rarely a 'one click hack'

Have a look at the WEP hacking tutorials here http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php

Maybe have a look at installing Debian on an old laptop http://debian.org/CD/netinst/

It's all good fun anyway.